# Why is Rails I18n returning "translation missing:" but still displaying the message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-i18n

I am using Devise in a Rails 4 app. I am displaying a flash message after signin.

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  set_flash_message :alert, I18n.t( 'users.after_signin_msg')
end
```

I have a translation file

```
#config/locales/users.en.yml
en:
  users: 
    after_signin_msg: "Hello and Welcome"
```

When a user signs in, the displayed flash message is

```
translation missing: en.devise.sessions.user.Hello and Welcome
```

Why is the Devise controller being displayed in the translation? And if Rails is looking under a Devise translation, why is the correct message being displayed as well?

How do I go about removing the `translation missing` text?

Comment: Is there another call to `t` when you display the flash?

Comment: yes there is, but under a different flash key (i.e., flash[:notice] rather than [:alert]). I just tried logging in to the app with `set_flash_message` commented out, and nothing is displayed under the :alert flash and the translation missing disappears. The other :notice flash displays perfectly in both cases, so I don't believe the :notice flash is affecting this.

Comment: Still sounds like how flash[:alert] is displayed is relevant to the question.

Comment: yes, you are correct. The `flash[:alert]` is being set by Devise's session#create action. I just had a look at the source. I had not realized that  `set_flash_message` is a Devise method that specifically references Devise translations. Changing my after_sign_in method to `flash[:notice] = t( 'users.after_signin_msg')` solved everything! Thanks for getting me looking in the right place!

Comment: @AndyHarvey you're right dear , little change i made was `I18n.t` instead of only `t`

Comment: feel free to add the answer. I would not have found this solution so quickly without your point in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Came across this for another `devise` translation error and thought I would add the solution that worked for me.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (translation missing: en.devise.registrations.edit.back)
```

Solved it by changing `t()` -> `I18n.t()` for the single instance causing issues in the template.

Works, but not sure why it was necessary.

@ImranNaqvi suggested this in the comments:

> @AndyHarvey you're right dear , little change i made was I18n.t instead of only t – ImranNaqvi Jul 23 '16 at 4:37